# Hide Tabs on product details page for specific product Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-view, tabs, magento2.2.4

I have a specific type of product. And I want to hide the Tabs on product details page for that product specifically. Is it possible and what is the best way to do that.

Comment: which type of products you have ?

Comment: gift card product type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this thing by writing small code.

What you can do is add add layout via event `layout_load_before`, you can use this event to add your dynamic layout.

Here is sample code for you, please modify as per your need, what you can do is create `event.xml` in your module

`[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- for differentiate layout.xml on product basis -->
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In your `[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore.php` file write below code

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if (!$product) {
          return $this;
        }
        if ($product->getMyvalue()) { // your condition
           $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('your_handler_name');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And now go to `[Vendor]\[Module]\view\frontend\layout\your_handler_name.xml` file and write your code.

This file only added to your specific condition of product

In your `your_handler_name.xml` layout file you can remove your tab like

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true" />       
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes is it possible for Simple and virtual product type,

you can override `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`  and `catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml` into your theme and juct put this code so it's effected only in simple and virtual product.

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true" />       
</body>
```

Hope it's help you.

Comment: Your most welcome !!